# Check login using Shared Preference

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have a code where I store the boolean value to indicate whether a user is logged in or not. I am accessing the shared preferences as shown below:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    // Intialize the shared preference
    sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Check here
}
```

I am checking after the layout is inflated and all the resources are bind. But my doubt is that should I initialize shared preference and check it before the `setContentView()` line because if a user is already logged in, I don't want to inflate the `layout` and bind resources to it and directly move to another `activity` which I think may speed up the process.

Currently I am doing this way:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Intialize the shared preference
    sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPref.getBoolean(LOGIN_PREFERENCE_KEY, false)){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

Comment: Good Thought... I am inflating after SharedPreference value check. if Its satisfy condition true else directly call to another activity

Comment: Not sure what you are actually asking. Just do it.

Comment: I am asking should I check if a User is logged in before setContentView() because in case a user is already logged in, I don't have to carry the heavy task of inflating the layout. @Henry

Comment: Why don't you use a splash screen to decide that.

Comment: Did you experience any problems when you tried it?

Comment: @MehulKanzariya if you want to check user before setContentView then do it :). I mean you only have to check either the user is logged in or not ? what is the use of view in that ? So you are safe there.

Comment: Actually, I don't see any performance improvements. Both the approaches are taking the same time. I want to know which one is a better approach. @Henry

Comment: IMO later one is safe approach if you want to check user logged in or not check it after setContentView or like ADM said if you have splash screen check it there.

Comment: Did you `return` early (before the `setContentView`) from the method or did you just call `finish`? In the latter case the view was still inflated.

Comment: I have added the code to the approach I am following. Please have a look. @Henry

Comment: Add a `return` directly after `finish`. Just calling `finish` does not take you out of the method, the rest is still executed.